# Losing SharedPrerences data after reboot

Tags: android, variables, sharedpreferences

I save two variables using the SharedPreferences when I press a button and restore it on `onCreate()`method and everything works just fine when closing and reopening the app, but after a reboot all values are set to default. Why is that? Do I have to save it in some other way to prevent losing values after reboot?

Comment: Do you call .apply()/.commit() on your SharedPreferences.Editor?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. I just said that everything works fine but only after reboot I get default values.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Sorry I was so dumb and didn't see my very foolish mistake. Before restoring variables I check if some alarm is on, but after reboot the alarm goes off so variables isn't restored. Sorry again for spamming